# Uncaught exception in Firebase runloop (3.0.0) workaround for Strings

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

According to the post in the link below the firebase runloop-3.0.0 error can be solved by setting the startAt() and endAt() parameters to non-integer values.

[Uncaught exception in Firebase runloop (3.0.0)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37724801/uncaught-exception-in-firebase-runloop-3-0-0)

Is it possible to implement same work around solution if your parameter is a string? For my case i use it to query a date (ex. startAt("09-2016")).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the problem has been solved in the latest update of the Firebase SDK,
Version 9.6 - September 21, 2016

https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android#9.6